# Issue Scaling Font to Screen Size

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with a navbar and a homepage. The navbar is fixed and the homepage takes up 100% of the screen. The viewer then scrolls down from the homepage to view the rest of the web content.

I'm having an issue with the font not scaling when viewing on a mobile device or devices with smaller screen sizes. I believe this is due to me changing the navbar to take up 100% width and for the homepage to be taking up 100% height. The text under section1 scales correctly (the font gets bigger when the screen is smaller).

How can I have the homepage and the navbar increase in font?

```css
h1{
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
             0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {

    background: #1A3742;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin: auto 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    background: gray;
    padding: 28px 0 26px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;

}

#top{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;

}
#home-content{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
a[href="#top"] {
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a img{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
.content {
    margin-left:75px;
    margin-top:25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content p{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header"> 
        <a href="#top">Name</a>
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="img" height="24" width="24">
        </a>
    </header>

    <div id="top">  
        <div id = "home-content">
            
            <h1>Top</h1>
            <h2>Sub title</h2>
            <p>
            This text does not scale at all.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section1"> 
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <div class = "content">

        <p> 
        This scales with the screen.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example on mobile that shows the top text not scaling, but the section1 scaling correctly.
[image]

That is a Galaxy S5 in google Chrome. The text in the homepage/top portion and navbar should be scaling similar to the way the section1 text does.
How can I fix it so everything scales to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

First, none of it is scaling. It's applying browser defaults as you've not set any font-size in the css provided. You can test it in the web inspector (remember to reload the page after activating it).

You can use vh (view height) or or vw (view width) as percentage messure for the font.

Comment: I understand that it using defaults, but why does section 1 font size increase but the navbar and top portion not increase in font size? I would expect both of them to have the same font size.

Comment: update your browser after activating the web inspector mobile mode, i saw the same and then remembered to update.

Comment: I refreshed, but that doesn't fix it. The #top has a height of 100% which changes the size of the text in it. I'm trying to figure out how I can get it to not do that, similar to the bottom portion which never changes. Not sure how to do this in a simple way. If I remove the height:100% in #top, everything works fine. However, I need to keep the height:100%

Comment: This is how it looks like (from your snippet, using web inspector, after refreshing): http://imgur.com/0CJTIoU

Comment: If you want the fonts to scale with the size of the screen, you can use vh or vw as stated, or even vmax (% of the larger size, either width or height)

Comment: Strange. I'm not seeing that at all. I'm using chrome's device mode and seeing it look like the screenshot shown in my post. My Galaxy S6 also shows it like my screenshot. I'll have to look into it more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113272/discussion-between-lordneo-and-eric).

Answer (score 0):

use media queries to adjust according to screen size
ex:
    @media screen and (max-width:1000px){
    #top{ 
    font-size : 40px; /*change it to whatever you need*/
    }
    }
change the max-width accordingly to manage perfectly for every screen

for more information on media queries
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries